# How can I track each "step" of a program in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging

For example, in my error_log, it says something like:

```
Error... require, include, a_function, another_function
```

Basically it tracks each step of the program. I want to implement something like this for debugging purposes. How do I "track" the execution of the program in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [debug_backtrace()](http://ru.php.net/debug_backtrace) and custom [error handler](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 0):

The [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) / [debug_print_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) functions :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `debug_backtrace()` as mentioned by others, I would recommend installing [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) and making use of the code profiler therein.  When coupled with a cachegrind application to analyze the profile, you can easily view and page through a full trace of your script's execution with execution times per function call.